# C++ library providing generic shared-resource locking wrapper

Tags: library, c++, multi-threading

I have a pool of threads that asynchronously acquire and execute tasks in a queue. Some of these tasks operate over some shared resources. I would like to:

1. Provide a contract that separates shared resources from task-specific resources
2. Through this contract, ensure that all shared resources are guarded by an appropriate lock (e.g., a mutex)

One option is a generalization of the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851314/scope-based-locking-wrapper-for-a-class). You provide some sort of `SharedResource<T>` class template. An instance of `SharedResource<T>` owns a shared resource of type `T` along with a mutex. It exposes some `acquire()` method that locks the internal mutex and returns a `LockedResource<T>` object, which holds the lock and a reference to the shared resource. On destruction, the `LockedResource<T>` object releases its lock. `LockedResource<T>` forwards all calls to the underlying `T` resource (e.g., by implementing `operator->()`). To support shared ownership of the underlying resource across tasks, you could also wrap the `SharedResource<T>` object's resource and mutex in an automatic reference counter (e.g., a `std::shared_ptr<std::tuple<T, std::mutex>>`). As intended, the effect of this solution is that it is necessary to acquire the lock prior to accessing the underlying resource.

This all seems very doable. Yet, it also seems like a convenient solution to a common problem, which makes me think it's probably already been solved by some library. Does the C++ standard library or Boost provide anything like this? If not, do any other libraries come to mind?

Comment: Better ask your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @RomeoNinov Why? I'm not asking how to implement a solution to a problem. I'm asking for existing software that implements a known solution. This is a classic software recommendation question.

Comment: [Here's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource#answer-351562) a source explicitly stating that this is the appropriate site to ask if a library exists to solve a problem, and that this question is off-topic for SO. [Here's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource/251135#251135) Robert Harvey's answer to the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late to this, but anyone finding this thread via Google should know that there is exactly this being adopted by the C++ core library, `synchronized_value<T>`:

> The basic idea is that `synchronized_value<T>` stores a value of typeT and a mutex.The `apply()` function then provides a means of accessing the stored value with the mutex locked, automatically unlocking the mutex afterwards.

- https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4033.html

GCC 13 already contains an implementation of this you can import from `<experimental>`

Comment: It's never too late to provide a useful answer